# Cannot Share a file to others using OneDrive API?

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to share a file in One-Drive using its API. When I hit it from postman I got a response with HTTP status 200 and when I looked into the One-Drive website it showed "Link sent to xxxxx@gmail.com", but I didn't get any mail regarding this to specified account. I used below POST method and the body to share it to others. How to share a file in One-Drive using API?

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/<item-id>/action.invite
{
  "requireSignIn": false, "sendInvitation": true, "roles": ["write"],  "recipients": [ { "email": "xxx@gmail.com" },{ "email": "yyy@gmail.com" }, ],
  "message": "hi"
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the invite email is not in the target user's junk folder?

Comment: yes.I checked user's spam also.